# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass within Pages#friends

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, undefined, null

I am trying to get my followers to display on the **pages/friends** however, I keep getting multiple errors like an ***undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass*** in my Pages#friends error. I am following Michael Harlts tutorials on follow/unfollow however, I needed to tweak a couple of things because I did not follow the entire thing.

When a user goes to their Friends link (pages/friends) I want it to display everyone who is following them. Like how my **users/index** displays everyone. Please see my code below. Any help of suggestions would be great.

**Pages/friends**

```
<h1>Friends</h1>

<% @user ||= current_user %>
 <% @users.each do |user| %>
     <center><%= link_to image_tag(user.avatar.url(:thumb)), user %></center>
     <strong><center><br><%= link_to user.name, user %></br></center></strong>
     <% if current_user.admin %>
 <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

**Pages/controller**

```
  def home
  end

  def about
  end

  def friends
  end

end
```

****Users/index***

```
<% provide(:title, 'All users') %>
<h1>All users</h1>

    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-med-8">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading center">

  <% @users.each do |user| %>
     <center><%= link_to image_tag(user.avatar.url(:thumb)), user %></center>
     <strong><center><br><%= link_to user.name, user %></br></center></strong>
     <% if current_user.admin %>

  <% @user ||= current_user %>
      <div class="stats">
        <a href="<%= friends_path(@user) %>">
          <strong id="following" class="stat">
            <%= @user.followed_users.count %>
          </strong>
          following
        </a>
        <a href="<%= friends_path(@user) %>">
          <strong id="followers" class="stat">
            <%= @user.followers.count %>
          </strong>
          followers
        </a>
      </div>


 <center><%= link_to "Delete", user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %></center>
<% end %>
<% end %>

<div class="center">
<%= will_paginate @users, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
</div>
</div>
```

**Routes**

```
devise_for :admins
  devise_for :users

  resources :posts
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end

  resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :user_friendships do 
      member do
        put :accept
      end
     end   

  get "users/show"


  root "pages#home"
  get 'feed', to: 'posts#index', as: :feed
  get "about" => "pages#about"
  get "friends" => 'pages#friends'


  match 'users/:id' => 'users#show', via: :get
  match 'users/:id' => 'users#index', via: :destroy


  match 'users/:id' => 'users#destroy', via: :get
  match 'users/:id' => 'users#destroy', via: :delete


  get '/:id', to: 'users#show'
```

**Users/controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy, :following, :followers]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy


  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 5)
  end


  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if @user 

        @posts = @user.posts.all
        render actions: :show 
    else
        render file: 'public/404', status: 404, formats: [:html]
    end  

def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Your account has been deleted."
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to root_path 
    end

  def admin_user
      redirect_to root_path unless current_user.admin?
  end


  def following
    @title = "Following"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followed_users.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  def followers
    @title = "Followers"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followers.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  end
end
```

**Relationships Controller**

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]


def create
    @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
    current_user.follow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Please post your `pages_controller` `friends` action, since you're getting the error in `pages#friends`. Make sure to include any `before_action` filters.

Comment: Are the controller’s methods actually empty? Then where do you define `@users` for the view?

Answer (score 3):

The error `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass` means that you're calling `.each` on an object that is `nil`.

For example, here, `@users` could be `nil`:

```
def index
  @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 5)
end
```

If you then call `<% @users.each ... %>`, you'll get the `undefined method` error. You've posted quite a lot of code above, so it's difficult to know exactly where that error is being thrown. Try and work out exactly where the error is being thrown (posting a stack trace would help), and work out which object is `nil`. Then work out *why* it's `nil` - is there no data? Or is your ActiveRecord query returning no results?

Hopefully that gives you some pointers as to where to start looking next.

**Edit:** As mmichael points out, the error is being caused due to the fact that `@users` was undeclared in `pages#friends`. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the error is on that line, it will perhaps be an empty array but not `nil`, the error is probably in the pages_controller that is not included.

Comment: It just has empty methods, so there is your error. You have to do something like `@users = User.all` there.

Comment: @Sam, you should update your answer as the error is due to missing `@users` declaration in `pages#friends`.

Answer (score 1):

As you're new, I'll give you another opinion. What I'm going to write is similar to `Sam`'s answer; I intend to help you appreciate how Rails works, to further your experience

---

**Objects**

You must remember that Rails is built on top of Ruby - an [*object-orientated* language](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_object_oriented.htm). This means every time you declare / use a `variable` inside Ruby, you're actually accessing an *object*, which Ruby treats as having a series of *methods*:

> Ruby is pure object-oriented language and everything appears to Ruby
>   as an object. Every value in Ruby is an object, even the most
>   primitive things: strings, numbers and even true and false. Even a
>   class itself is an object that is an instance of the Class class. This
>   chapter will take you through all the major functionalities related to
>   Object Oriented Ruby.

I write this because Ruby's object-orientated structure is much different than handling *variables* in the "traditional" sense -- in the simplest description, it means that Ruby presumes that objects are ALWAYS present (it just builds them from the `NilClass`), allowing you call "empty" data sets without running into "undeclared" issues

The problems occur when you try and run methods like `.each` on empty / nil objects. If you do this, errors like the one you alluded to occur; preventing you from being able to perform the functionality which you intended

--

**Fix**

Your error basically means you **haven't declared your variable**.

After seeing your code, the most obvious problem will be here:

```
#app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
Class PagesController < ApplicationController
   def friends
       # normally, you'd define your @instance_variables here
   end
end
```

I see that your `friends` action does not declare your `@users` variable, which is required to perform the `@users.each` method. As recommended by `Sam`, the first step is to ensure you're able to declare this value, allowing you to loop through it as required:

```
#app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
Class PagesController < ApplicationController
   def friends
      @users = User.all
   end
end
```